# Android New Test Type

Tags: android, unit-testing, jacoco

In Android test framework there are two types namely, `Local unit tests` and `Instrumented tests`. Is it possible to create duplicate of the Instrumented tests?

I want only some tests to be executed when I select the this duplicate. Or in other words I wanna distinguish between different tests in "Instrumented Tests". Is this possible?

Please ask for any details you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to duplicate tests, you can just annotate them using some of the Android Testing Support Library provided [filters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/filters/package-summary.html) or you can create you own annotation.

Then using [AndroidJunitRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) you can run tests with or without a particular annotation

Filter test run to tests with given annotation:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```